# Swift - UIView addConstraints not working

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I was playing with Swift, when suddenly, nothing appear.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var DiabolicView: UIView = UIView();//With UIButton it's working
    DiabolicView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
    DiabolicView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 67, height: 67)
    DiabolicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();//To see the view
    view.addSubview(DiabolicView);

    view.addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: DiabolicView,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: -100
    )]);
}
```

Yes, really nothing [(screen of nothing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJajq.png)

But when I replace the **Diabolic UIView** by a cool **UIButton**, the *Red Square appear* :

[Screen of the magic Red Square when I replace UIView by UIButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVh9T.png)

So, the question is, why I can't see the UIView ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints work with a `UIButton` because buttons have an *[intrinsic content size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize)* - they can decide how big they want to be.

`UIView`, on the other hand, doesn't.* You need to either:

- Add constraints to specify the view's size, or
- Subclass `UIView` and override `intrinsicContentSize()` to return the default size of your view.

Setting the frame's size as you're currently attempting won't cut it - this frame is ignored by the layout engine.

---

* - The default implementation of this method returns `CGSizeMake(UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric)`, or `(-1, -1)`, which is why you don't see your view at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Aaron Brager**, I can see the Reeed Squaaare !!!

```
import UIKit

class SweetView: UIView {
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 67, height: 67);
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var DiabolicView: SweetView = SweetView();
        DiabolicView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
        DiabolicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();//To see the view
        view.addSubview(DiabolicView);

        view.addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: DiabolicView,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: view,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: -100
        )]);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Thank you ! :D

Answer (score -1):

Use `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()` to update constrains.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no Red Square :'(

Answer (score -1):

you are missing one thing and that is x,y coordinates of the Diabolic UIView.

Comment: try this view.layOutIfNeeded(), but do it in viewDidAppear

Comment: check translate autoresizingmask into contraints